# Pig Joining with more than one condition.?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I'm joining two tables but in ON condition i use more than one column to join in AND
like

```
select * from t1 join t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2 and t1.col3 = t2.col3
```

i did this in Hive this is working but not pig

when i store the file is 0kb

Comment: what do you mean by this `i did this in Hive this is working but not pig`? This is hive query, do expect to run this on Pig?

Comment: can you add the pig script tried  with input and expected output

Comment: Sorry about that Young Hobbit, i mean to say that this join is working perfectly fine which is a hive query. But i tried to do the same in pig the file which i try to store id 0kb. In Pig i did like this "a= join table1 by (col1,col2,col3), tableb by (col1,col2,col3); Store a into /user/hive/result;"

Comment: Hey Murali, the thing im trying to achive is simple i have 2 tables with 3 column  i need to join all the  columns and if they match i need that result to be stored, thats it

Comment: @Maharaj how do you load the two tables post the LOAD statement and was it run in mapreduce mode and some sample data of the file. Always post whatever you have tried with some sample input and expected output to get a prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all Guys, but the real reason that the output file is 0kb is in table 1 there is a string column which is initcap and in table 2 the column is all small letters, @Vignesh I loaded the table with -useHCatalog -x Mapreduce. now im getting the result. Once again thank you all guys